# Re-run Function on Click

Tags: jquery, flip

I'm using the flip jquery plugin.

I have an album cover and a link to view the song list of the album. When I click the "View Song List" link, I want to flip the album cover over to view the list of songs. At the same time, I want to change the "View Song List" link to read "View Album Art". When the user clicks the "View Album Art" link, the album should flip over to the front again and show the art and change the "View Album Art" link to read "View Song List" again. This works OK.

Now, when I click the "View Song List" link again, I would expect the same thing to happen all over again - flipping the album over. But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here it is - see the bottom box with the album covers: 
http://maplemountainchorus.org/mandy/index2.html

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){

$(".flipPad a.viewSongList").click(function(){
$(".flipbox").flip({
        direction: 'lr',
        color: '#fff',
        content: $(".flipbox").addClass("removeBkgrnd").html('<p>Here is the song list.</p>'),
        onBefore: function(){$(".flipPad a.viewSongList").html('View Album Art').addClass("viewAlbumArt")},
        onEnd: function(){$(".flipPad a.viewSongList.viewAlbumArt").click(function(){
            $(".flipbox").removeClass("removeBkgrnd").html('');
            $(this).removeClass("viewAlbumArt").html('View Song List');

        });
        }
    })
    return false;

});

});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<section id="media">
    <div id="buyMusic">
        <div id="musicSlider" class="flexslider" style="background-color:#000;">
              <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                  <div class="flipbox sweetDreams"></div>
                  <div class="flipPad">
                    <a href="#" class="viewSongList">View Song List</a>
                  </div>    
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="flipbox winterWonderland"></div>
                  <div class="flipPad">
                    <a href="#" class="viewSongList">View Song List</a>
                  </div>    
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="flipbox rightCry"></div>
                  <div class="flipPad">
                    <a href="#" class="viewSongList">View Song List</a>
                  </div>    
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="flipbox mandy"></div>
                  <div class="flipPad">
                    <a href="#" class="viewSongList">View Song List</a>
                  </div>    
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="flipbox platinum"></div>
                  <div class="flipPad">
                    <a href="#" class="viewSongList">View Song List</a>
                  </div>    
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="flipbox patsy"></div>
                  <div class="flipPad">
                    <a href="#" class="viewSongList">View Song List</a>
                  </div>    
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.flipbox{width:236px;height:237px;float:left;}
.flipbox.winterWonderland{background:url('../images/music-winter-wonderland.jpg') no-  repeat;}
.flipbox.sweetDreams{background:url('../images/music-sweet-dreams.jpg') no-repeat;}
.flipbox.rightCry{background:url('../images/music-right-cry.jpg') no-repeat;}
.flipbox.platinum{background:url('../images/music-platinum.jpg') no-repeat;}
.flipbox.patsy{background:url('../images/music-patsy.jpg') no-repeat;}
.flipbox.mandy{background:url('../images/music-mandy.jpg') no-repeat;}
.flipbox.removeBkgrnd{background-image:none;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid red;width:236px;height:237px;}
.flipPad{float:left;padding-left:4.8em;}
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle.net example; and re-state the problems you are facing. Currently, I was not able to understand it. :(

Comment: Sorry - here it is on a page: http://maplemountainchorus.org/mandy/index2.html

Comment: I want to click the View Song List - have the album cover flip over to view the list and at the same time change "View Song List" to "View Album Art". Then click "View Album Art" to flip the album cover back over to view the front again. Then, if the user clicks the "View Song List" link again, flip the album cover over again and do the same thing - like toggling.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line

`$(this).removeClass("viewAlbumArt").html('View Song List');`

here `$(this)` refers to `$(".flipbox")` and not `$(".flipPad a.viewSongList")` so this event
`$(".flipPad a.viewSongList.viewAlbumArt")` is always being executed later.

Comment: Thanks - I replaced this with .flipPad a.viewSongList - but still getting the same problem. Here's a link to maybe help troubleshoot: http://maplemountainchorus.org/mandy/index2.html